# Using Powershell to replace entire line of special chars (password hashes)

Tags: regex, powershell, hash, char

I'm stuck with a powershell command.

I need to replace a password hash by another one.

I want to replace : `*%%#%%"%'$'*,),.20.2-41"*`

by : `"'%(&&)$Se2EEdEEE"%%"`

I'm using :

```
powershell -Command "(gc myfile.ini) -replace '*%%#%%"%'$'*,),.20.2-41"*', '"'%(&&)$Se2EEdEEE"%%"' | Set-Content myfile.ini"
```

I'm stuck with the format of the request, the quotes and double quotes in the password hash really don"t help me..

If someone got e better way to deal with hashes or a solution to get it working with Powershell, it will be really appreciated!

Comment: Double the single quotes, and use `[regex]::Escape` to escape special chars in the string automatically. Or  use the `.Replace()` non-regex method on the string if the strings are fixed.

Comment: You can use Regex.